# Matrix4 transformation as per screen size in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using matrix4 for move, change scale and rotate widgets, it is working perfectly, But the problem is, when I share the matrix4 value to another device the position and scale of widgets changes as per screen size,
I want to keep the position for all screen sizes, how to convert matrix4 as per screen size?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: before sharing scale your matrix by (1/screenWidth, 1/screenHeight) and on the other device scale it back by (otherDeviceScreenWidth, otherDeviceScreenHeight)

Comment: Thank you for your reply!!    i tried your answer i multiply the each value in matrix by (screenWidth / screenHeight) and divide it by (otherDeviceScreenWidth / otherDeviceScreenHeight) but it not worked, is there i did any mistake?

Comment: you should scale the matrix - and not multiply each 16 values - i mean methods: `scale` or `scaled`

Comment: Hello sir, I did matrix.scale(1/screenWidth, 1/screenHeight); on one device and matrix.scale(1/otherDeviceScreenWidth , 1/otherDeviceScreenHeight); on another device but it not worked. can you share code snippets? Thank you!

Comment: `(1/screenWidth, 1/screenHeight)` on the first device and `(otherDeviceScreenWidth, otherDeviceScreenHeight)` on the another - check my first comment above

Comment: Hello sir, It also have some changes in position and scale between two devices.

Comment: some? what in particular?

Comment: In position of widget both are contains some changes particularly in x-axis.

Comment: i have no idea what you mean, sorry...

Comment: It's ok Thank you for your help sir.

Comment: if there are any differences then post screenshots from both devices

Comment: Ok sir, i will share screenshots with you, can you give your email Id?

Comment: use https://pasteboard.co/